# Hodge Theory for Smooth Projective Varieties

Tags: sheaf-cohomology, hodge-theory

Given a smooth complex projective variety $X$, I know that by the "Hodge Theory" we can compute the dimensions of the cohomology groups of the structural sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ by:
$$H^p(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong H^0(X,\Omega^p) $$
(where $\Omega^p$ is the sheaf of regular $p$-forms) by the more general isomorphism:
$$H^p(X,\Omega^q)\cong H^q(X,\Omega^p)$$
 I know that all of this comes by harmonic analysis, but has very strong applications to algebraic geometry, as the dimension of the global sections of $\Omega^p$ is far easier to compute.

Now, I wondered if it is was possible to get a hint of that isomorphism just working within the framework of algebraic geometry, computing it directly as cohomology of sheaves. What I was thinking about is this:
$$0\to \mathbb{C}\to \Omega^\bullet $$
gives a resolution of the constant sheaf on $X$, and so by tensoring I get a resolution of the structural sheaf:
$$ 0\to \mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X\otimes_\mathbb{C}\Omega^\bullet$$
The problem now is that in order to get the cohomology I have to apply the functor of global sections, but the tensor product of sheaves is the sheafification of the presheaf which assigns $U\mapsto \mathcal{O}_X(U)\otimes_\mathbb{C}\Omega^p(U)$ so I really don't know how to work with them (I can just handle this object locally) and this makes difficult to compute kernels and images necessary to get the cohomology groups. Any hints or references to books or notes where I can learn something more are highly accepted!

Comment: Just asking: Have you looked at _Principles of Algebraic Geometry_ by Griffiths and Harris?

Comment: I gave it a look by now, it is very fascinating but it is still working with Khaler manifold and harmonic forms... I'd like to find just a way to realize that isomorphism in such simple cases but completely algebraically (still I know harmonic analysis provides more and sophisticated tools)

Comment: Do we really have an isomorphism $H^p(X,\Omega^q)\simeq H^q(X,\Omega^p)$ ? I thought that you only have a semi-linear isomorphism. In other words $\overline{H^{pq}}\simeq H^{qp}$. Moreover, this symmetry ($h^{pq}=h^{qp}$) only holds in characteristic zero. For this reasons, I doubt there are any purely algebraic interpretation of this. (Anyway, I am really not sure what you are trying to do in your last paragraph, $\mathcal{O}_X\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\Omega^\bullet$ seems very weird to me)

Comment: I think you're right, in fact what I used sometimes was that simmetry in the dimension of those groups, but, as vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, I thought it was sufficient to get they were isomorphic (apparentely it is not). About the last thing I tried to follow Warner, "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups". There he introduces sheaf cohomology axiomatically, and then realizes a cohomology theory before finding an acyclic resolution of the constant sheaf and then tensoring this resolution with the sheaf of which we want the cohomology, obtaining so the wanted resolution.

Comment: Well they are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$ since they are two vector spaces of the same dimension. But there are no canonical $\mathbb{C}$-isomorphism, only a semi-linear one.

Comment: The thing is : $\Omega^\bullet$ is not an acyclic resolution of $\mathbb{C}$. This is the whole point $\Omega^q$ has some non trivial cohomology groups $H^p(X,\Omega^q)$ in general.

Comment: Thank you, I was misled by the fact that it is an acyclic resolution for $\mathbb{R}$ thanks to partitions of unity. I'll try to find some more about it and about Dolbeaut Cohomology on Griffiths and Harris.